# Exception thrown using filter

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable, stack-overflow, dataview

I have `DataTable` and its filter by `DataView` and RowFilter using string. Its working fine. But when sting create a huge line then got stackoverflow exception in `DataView` row filter.

```
dv.RowFilter = strFilter
```

String strFilter is like below. Only filter by two column Division and Location

```
strFilter=([Division] LIKE ('Division 2') or [Division] LIKE ('%|Division 2') or [Division] LIKE ('%|Division 1') AND [Location] LIKE ('%Location1') or [Location] LIKE ('Locaion2|%').....
```

Instead of RowFilter I used `LINQ`, but its not returned to the correct table

```
 Dim query = dv.Table.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(m) strFilterOption.Contains(m.Field(Of String)("Division")) AndAlso strFilterOption.Contains(m.Field(Of String)("Location")))

 dv = query.AsDataView()
 Dim dtFillData As DataTable=dv.ToTable
```

How do I do this using `LINQ` or any other solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, start using `OrElse` instead of `AndAlso`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like the following:

```
Dim query = dv.Table.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(m) m.Field.ToString()(Of String)("Division").Contains("Division 2") ElseOr m.Field(Of String)("Division").EndsWith("|Division 2") ElseOr m.Field(Of String)("Division").EndsWith("|Division 1")  AndAlso ..... ))
```

Comment: But its is a dynamic string. And it is multiple [Division] and [Location]